# Can I detect the point of impact without looking at it?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, dg.differential-geometry

I'm going to postpone the motivation for this question because the question itself involves no complicated maths and may well have a very simple solution so I don't want to put anyone off with high falutin' symbols.

Here's the question.  I have a smooth curve $c \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which does not intersect the $x$-axis.  As $t \to 0$, this curve approaches the $x$-axis.  I want to find out if it has a point of impact.  At my disposal, I have any smooth function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is constant along the $x$-axis.  I know that for any such $f$, $f \circ c \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ extends to a smooth function $[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ (that is, all one-sided derivatives exist at the origin and are the limits of the corresponding derivatives as we approach the origin) with value $f(0,0)$ at $0$.  So:

> Is there some $f$ (satisfying the condition) such that the composition $f \circ c$ tells me that $c$ approaches a particular point on the $x$-axis?

If the answer to that is "yes", then my follow-up question is about the derivatives of $c$ at the point of approach.

Here are some comments and partial results:

1. I'm allowed to use **any** information about the compositions $f \circ c$: their values, their derivatives, and so forth.
2. The $y$-value of $c$ easily extends to a smooth function $[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ since the second projection $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is one of our detectors.  Moreover, it extends taking the value $0$ at $t = 0$.
3. I can show that the $x$-value of $c$ is bounded as $t$ approaches $0$.  If it weren't, I could stick bump functions along the image of $c$ with disjoint support and that were $0$ on the $x$-axis.  As they have disjoint support, their sum, call it $f$, is a smooth function and is at the disposal of my detection agency.  So there is some sequence $(t_n) \to 0$ such that $f \circ c(t_n) = 1$, but $f(0,0) = 0$ so this violates my condition.
4. I can show that if $c$ approaches the $x$-axis with any sort of speed then I can detect its point of impact (and all derivatives).  To do this, I use the function $g \colon (x,y) \mapsto x y$.  So long as *some* derivative of the (extended) $y$-value of $c$ is non-zero at $0$, I can use this to find out the $x$-value by differentiating $g \circ c$ that many times.
5. If $c$ approaches the $x$-axis infinitely slowly, has a point of impact, and the $x$-value extends to a smooth function $[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ (so then $c$ extends to a smooth function $[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$) then I cannot detect the actual point of impact.  This is because I can use the chain rule to find the value of any derivative of $f \circ c$ and each term vanishes because either it involves a derivative of the $y$-value (assumed zero) or it involves a pure $x$-derivative of $f$ (zero by assumption on $f$ as we're then on the $x$-axis).

So it seems to me that it's a reasonable conjecture that I can't show that $c$ has a point of impact, if it approaches infinitely slowly.  However, the above is not a proof of that fact.

---

**Motivation** I'm trying to finish off the details of an example of a Froelicher space (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Froelicher+space).  The space in question, let's call it $X$, is the quotient of the plane by the $x$-axis.  By the rules for taking quotients, the smooth functions on this space are simply the smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are constant along the $x$-axis.  I want to work out the smooth curves.  Let $c \colon \mathbb{R} \to X$ be a smooth curve.  It's straightforward to show that $c$ lifts to a smooth curve $U_c \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $U_c$ is the complement of the preimage of the collapsed point.  As $U_c$ is (easily shown to be) open, it decomposes as a union of intervals.  On each interval, $c$ is a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which approaches the $x$-axis at the end-points.  So the question is as to what can be said as $c$ gets near one of these end-points.  That's the source of this question.

---

**Edit** Added in response to Bjorn's answer.  The underlying question is:

> What are the smooth functions $c \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$?

(Blah, blah, [Froelicher space structure](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Froelicher+space), blah, blah)

Thus the point of the question is not "I have a curve, what is it?" but "Which curves can I get?".  However, I figured that the question "What are the smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$?" wouldn't get much interest, but something about extending smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ might!

**Also** If, as I suspect, I can get curves with no definite "point of impact", can I limit how bad these curves must be in some way?  Can I put some bound on their ($x$-)derivatives, or at least limit how fast they go to infinity?

Comment: Two clarification questions: (1) I assume that $t$ is the variable parameterizing $(0,1)$?  (2) What is a "point of impact"?

Comment: @Theo: (1) Yes.  (2) An attempt at making it sound more interesting than it possibly is!  By "point of impact" I mean the point (if it exists) where the curve hits the x-axis.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew's comments showed me that in my first answer I was misunderstanding several aspects of his question.  Since I am still not entirely sure that I am capturing the spirit of the problem, let be begin this answer by stating in my own words (in very dry mathematical terms) what I interpret the question(s) to be, so that he or someone else can correct me if necessary.

---

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of smooth functions $f \colon \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$ whose restriction to the $x$-axis is constant.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of smooth functions $c \colon (0,1) \to \mathbf{R}$ such that for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$,

- the function $f \circ c \colon (0,1) \to \mathbf{R}$ extends to a smooth function $[0,1) \to \mathbf{R}$ (in the sense that all one-sided derivatives exist at the origin and equal the one-sided limits of the corresponding derivatives), and
- $\lim_{t \to 0^+} f(c(t)) = f(0,0)$.

**Question 1:** If $c \in \mathcal{C}$, must $\lim_{t \to 0^+} c(t)$ exist?  (Actually, Andrew is also asking more generally what one can say about $c$ if the limit does not exist.)

**Question 2:** Is there a rule (function) $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{F}^r$ for some positive integer $r$, say taking $c$ to $(f_{1,c},\ldots,f_{r,c})$, such that $f_{1,c}$ is independent of $c$, and $f_{2,c}$ depends only on $f_{1,c} \circ c$, and $f_{3,c}$ depends only on $f_{1,c} \circ c$ and $f_{2,c} \circ c$, and so on, together with a rule (function) $R$ that takes as input a sequence of smooth functions $(g_1,\ldots,g_r)$ from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbf{R}$ and outputs a point in $\mathbf{R}^2$ such that for every $c \in \mathcal{C}$, we have $R(f_{1,c}\circ c,\ldots,f_{r,c} \circ c) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} c(t)$ whenever the latter exists?

**Question 3:** Same as Question 2, but with $\lim_{t \to 0^+} c'(t)$ in place of $\lim_{t \to 0^+} c(t)$.

---

**Answer to Question 1:** No.  A negative answer was essentially given already by Andrew himself.  Namely, let $c(t) := (\sin 1/t,e^{-1/t})$.  This $c(t)$ has the following properties: the $x$-coordinate is bounded, the derivatives of the $x$-coordinate grow at most polynomially in $1/t$ as $t \to 0^+$, and the $y$-coordinate and derivatives of the $y$-coordinate decay to $0$ exponentially as $t \to 0^+$.  As explained by Andrew, for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$, the chain rule shows that $f(c(t))$ extends to a smooth function $[0,1) \to \mathbf{R}$ whose value at $0$ is $f(0,0)$ and whose higher derivatives at $0$ are all $0$. $\square$

**Answer to Questions 2 and 3:** Yes.  In fact, we can do it with $r=2$, and with both $f_{1,c}$ and $f_{2,c}$ independent of $c$.  Namely, use $f_1(x,y)=y$ and $f_2(x,y)=e^x y$.  From $f_1 \circ c$ and $f_2 \circ c$, we may recover not only the $y$-coordinate of $c$ as $f_1 \circ c$, but also the $x$-coordinate of $c$ as $\log (f_2(c(t))/f_1(c(t)))$.  So the whole function $c(t)$, and hence any property of $c(t)$, can be detected. $\square$

Comment: Excellent!  I hadn't thought of using _two_ (or r) functions simultaneously.  That's an extremely useful tool to have learnt.  Question (4) is still outstanding: is there some intrinsic characterisation of those curves c satisfying the condition (ie without reference to f).  However, although that is my implicit question, it wasn't really the question in the question so I know I'm being a bit cheeky tacking it on the end!  I'll have a think about what you've written and check that I understand it all.  Incidentally, why use e^x y and not just x y?

Comment: You're right; I could have just used xy.  (I was worrying about a problem that doesn't exist.)

Comment: Thinking about this a little, I realised that the counterexample to Question 1 is what I was really looking for.  Questions 2 and 3 seem still in the mindset of your first question (that c is unknown, rather than which c satisfy the condition).  Working through the details of the counterexample then showed me how to adapt my proof that I can't detect the point of impact into a characterisation of those curves that satisfy the condition-the basic idea is that the y-value goes to 0 faster than any of the derivatives of the x-value.  I'll put the details at the nlab.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that everything can be recovered, if $f$ is chosen suitably!

There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ possibilities for $c$, so we can fix an injection $c \mapsto u_c$ from the set of possible $c$ into the set of real numbers.  Let $y_c$ be the $y$-coordinate of $c(1/2)$, so $y_c \ne 0$.

In the examples you give, you allow $f$ to depend on $c$, so I will take $f(x,y) := \frac{u_c}{y_c} y$.

**Claim:** I can recover $c$ from $f \circ c$.  (So in particular, any information you want about its limiting behavior as $t \to 0$ can be recovered too.)

**Proof:** Evaluating $f \circ c$ at $1/2$ gives $u_c$, which tells me what $c$ is.

Comment: If you're willing to commit such abuses, why not just let $f$ be the constant function $u_c$?

Comment: @Tom: I had misread the sentence before the blockquote as requiring $f(0,0)=0$, but after re-reading, I think that he is not requiring this, so you are right.  Your solution is even better!  Anyway, I did not mean for this to be an obnoxious answer, but rather one that would encourage Andrew to make precise what he is really looking for (since I am sure it is not this!)

Comment: I've voted for your answer _because_ of your comment!  I think that answers that expose vagueness are worthwhile.  I do have a mild problem with the answer: to know what function to use, I have to know c already, which means that I know what c is!  But more fundamentally, I'm trying to define the set of possible curves but to do what you suggest I need to already know it.  In addition, whilst I can pick f how I like, I can only really pick it based on prior information from other f's. (ctd ...)

Comment: ... (ctd)   Thus, for example, I first probe with (x,y) -> y to get the y-value, and then based on that information I pick some other f (e.g. if y has some non-zero derivative, I can pick (x,y) -> xy).  Is that any clearer?  (I've also added a comment to the question to hopefully make it a little clearer.)